# controller private member binding by ninject

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I have a MVC application using the Ninject.Mvc3 package as well as a NUnit testing project for it.

All controllers inherit from the following base controller

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    [Inject]
    protected IRepository Repository { get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

`NinjectWebCommon.RegisterServices` looks like

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Settings.InjectNonPublic = true;
    kernel.Bind<IRepository>().To<Repository>().InRequestScope();

    // ...
}
```

While running the web project, binding works.

However, how should I set Ninject kernel in the testing project to bind the Repository member in controller? I can not figure out how it is done, that Repository member uses kernel from NinjectWebCommons to resolve binding. Text search on project gives me nothing.

[UPD]:

```
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Settings.InjectNonPublic = true;
        kernel.Bind<IRepository>().To<Repository>().InRequestScope(); 
        var controller = kernel.Get<BlahBlahBlahController>();
        controller.SetFakeControllerContext();
        //...
```

This is how I should set Ninject kernel in the testing project. The second part of question is still unclear for me.